# maven calls external script on both Linux and Windows platforms

Tags: shell, maven, batch-file, pom.xml, exec-maven-plugin

I need to run an external script on both Linux and MS-Windows platforms.

1. Do I use the right plugin `exec-maven-plugin`?
2. Is there a more suitable plugin?
3. What filename should I put in `<executable>....</executable>`?

   ```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.1</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>compile-jni</id>
               <phase>compile</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>exec</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <executable>./compile-jni</executable>
                   <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/cpp</workingDirectory>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

I use the same `Makefile` for both platforms Linux/MS-Windows

**My script `compile-jni.bat`:**

```
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
bash -c "make"
```

**My script `compile-jni.sh`:**

```
#!/bin/sh
make
```

### UPDATE:

Two colleagues have suggested alternatives:

1. Use a variable `script.extension`
   change `<executable>./compile-jni${script.extension}</executable>` in the `pom.xml`
   and append the variable within the command line `mvn compile -Dscript.extention=.bat`
2. or set the Visual Studio environment variables before calling maven:

   ```
   call "C:\%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
   mvn compile #(the same script 'bash -c "make"' works on both platforms)
   ```

But on both solutions, Eclipse users may be stucked... I am still looking for an automatic and elegant solution...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Finally, I mixed the ideas => the `<profiles>` are used to set an internal variable `script.extension` depending on the operating system:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>Windows</id>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>Windows</family>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <script.extension>.bat</script.extension>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>unix</id>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>unix</family>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <script.extension>.sh</script.extension>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then I use the variable to complete the script filename:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>compile-jni</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>./compile-jni${script.extension}</executable>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

<kbd>⚠   As noticed by [Maksim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1490636/maksim-kostromin) for maven 3.5.4 move up the section `<configuration>` as shown below:</kbd>

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <executable>./compile-jni${script.extension}</executable>
  </configuration>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>compile-jni</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
     </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have moved the working directory from the `pom.xml` to the shell script. In order to simplify maintenance, the common stuff is moved within this shell scrip. Therefore, the batch file use this shell script:

**`compile-jni.bat`**:

```
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
bash compile-jni.sh
```

**`compile-jni.sh`**:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd src/main/cpp
make
```

Comment: problem with your configuration: move out configuration section from execution tag to root plugin declaration. ie `//plugin/executions/execution/configuration` -> `//plugin/configuration` otherwise I'm getting error: `The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid` on latest maven 3.5.4

Answer (score 5):

An example of running sh script.

This just does a `chmod` for the sh script. Keep in mind if you have a sh script, you should definitely do a `chmod` before performing other operations such as running the actual script, so having this as an example, you can do the first `<execution>` as below and add another `<execution>` to run your script.

For the batch file, you can have only one `<execution>` to run your script

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.codehaus.mojo.version}</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                    <id>script-chmod</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>chmod</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>+x</argument>
                            <argument>yourscript.sh</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and you would probably want to add a profile depending on which machine you are:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>!windows</family>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <plugin>
      <!-- add your exec-maven-plugin here -->
    </plugin>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Hope this will be a start for what you need

Comment: Humm.... my `pom.xml` is 120 lines long: I call also other scripts as `make clean`. I am afraid `<profile>` will almost double my `pom.xml` size, isn't it... :-(

Comment: :) I have a 1k lines long pom.xml, so don't worry about that

Comment: 1k lines :o Thank you for your help. I finally mixed all the ideas. I will post my final solution in another answer. But I validate your answer. Cheers

Comment: the profile needs to wrap the <plugin> with <build> and <plugins>.